# Can I use enter as an input?

Tags: c++

I am trying to allow the user to either enter a string or just hit enter, and in that case I would use a default string.

```
cout << "Where should I save the exam (default (./)exam.txt): " ;
cin >> exam_filename;
```

But right now you can enter a string and it works fine, but if you hit enter it just keeps waiting for the user to type something.  Any suggestions??

Okay so when I do this:

```
string exam_filename;
getline(cin, exam_filename);
if (exam_filename.empty())
  // set to default string
```

now it always sets the string to the default string.  It never gives me a chance to enter anything it just moves on the next part of the program autmoatically.

Answer (score 4):

You really want to read a line. Just do it:

```
string exam_filename;
getline(cin, exam_filename);
if (exam_filename.empty())
  // set to default string
```

Comment: When I put in that code though it just skips over letting the user input.  Like it just moves on to the next part of the program and sets the filename to the default string no matter what?

Comment: @user1852078, Search on SO for "[c++] getline skipping". There are *tons* of hits.